# Flip image in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a collection of small images (bellow “Some examples” in the left column ) I would like to flip one at the time.
I imagine that they flip and a new image is shown (like flipping a card).

Is there a jQuery plug in for this, or can I do it with ordinary jQuery?

[Link to site](http://www.dvdboxswap.com)

//Johan

Answer (score 1):

Flip!: http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

**Edit:** I also really like the jQuery Cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
It does loads of transitions so in your case it might be overkill, but just a tip if you want other cool effects.

Comment: I tried the cycle, but it seens that it dosent work good with a lot of small images. It lagd...